# Directory structure for rest api using restify

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I am creating rest api using restify. I searched for some boilerplate, none seems convincing. Can you suggest some boilerplate, or at least a directory structure that should be adopted. How to deal with imports?
All tutorials and blogs deal with simple todo app ..without any directory level implementation. I don't know how to structure my app.

Comment: look at open source projects for ideas on how you would best setup your project.

Comment: @Darkrum can you tell some using restify? Only open source project I saw using restify are very small, so they only have 4-5 routes